# mongoose one field multiple validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my custom validator for mongoose. Is there more convenient way to do a multiple validation for one field? It works but i think it's not the best way. All my attempts to make a multiple validation via native mongoose validator are crashed.

```
        schema.pre('save', function(callback) {
        var self = this;

        function nameLength (){
            var Regex1 = /^.{4,12}$/;
            if (Regex1.test(self.username)=== false){
                return(" Username must be between 4 and 12 characters long");
            }else{
                return(0);
            }
        }

        function nameSymbols () {
            var Regex1 = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
            if (Regex1.test(self.username) === false) {
                return (" Only roman letters and numbers can be used");
            } else {
                return (0);
            }
        }

        function passwordLength (){
            var Regex1 = /^.{8,50}$/;
            if (Regex1.test(self.password)=== false){
                return("Password must be between 8 and 50 characters long");
            }else{
                return(0);
            }
        }


        var f1 = nameLength();
        var f2 = nameSymbols();
        var f3 = passwordLength();


        var val = {};
        val.checkUsername = [f1, f2].filter(function(string){return string});
        val.checkPassword = [f3].filter(function(string){return string});




        if(val.checkUsername.length == 0){
            delete val.checkUsername
        }else if((val.checkPassword.length == 0)){
            delete val.checkPassword
        };



        for(var key in val){
            console.log(key);
            if(key){
                var err = new RegError(val);
                callback(err);
            }else{
                callback();
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do I would say your approach is fine. The only adjustments I would make would be related to style (it could be terser).

However, there is a flaw in your code that stands out:

If the user name is correct, the password rule never gets checked. Therefore, the password will invoke your callback with an error even if the password is corect.

```
if (val.checkUsername.length == 0) {
  delete val.checkUsername
} 
if ((val.checkPassword.length == 0)) {
  delete val.checkPassword
}
```